# special characters in eclipse path reason eclipse does not start anymore after installing lombok?

Tags: lombok

My eclipse.exe is in the following directory:

```
D:\dev\eclipse-jee+ServerToolsWeblogic+Jboss>
```

I installed lombok in eclipse by doing (in Git-bash on a windows machine)

```
java - jar /c/Users/isc30565/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.8/lombok-1.18.8.jar
```

I chose the location of eclipse.exe. Then in eclipse.ini I see:

```
-vmargs
...
-javaagent:D:\dev\eclipse-jee\+ServerToolsWeblogic\+Jboss\lombok.jar
```

With this line eclipse does not start anymore. Is this because of the special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks like. That's an interesting bug! Feel free to file this one over at [the lombok issue tracker](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues) – but please try to remove the backslashes in front of the plusses in your `eclipse.ini` file and report if that solves the issue.